# What is the method to create a sqlalchemy engine for a .db file rather than a sqlite file?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to access a .db file through sqlalchemy in python. Currently I'm running into the error "OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file"

My code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func

#Create Engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///material/formulary_data.db")

#reflect an existing database into a new model
Base = automap_base()
#reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

I'm finding few resources on the differences between a .db file and a .sqlite file.

Comment: What format/backend is a ".db" file?

Comment: I'm unaware. I believe the .db file is from an oracle database originally. I'm pretty unfamiliar with this line of work.

Comment: You'll need to figure that out before anything else. ".db" has no specific meaning and doesn't tell us anything. If it is an Oracle file (which seems unlikely?), you'll need an Oracle server to serve it. If you have a Unix system available, you might try typing (on the command line) `file formulary_data.db` and see if that gives you any clues.